# How to put a javascript array number in html with document.getElementById?

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, getelementbyid

Does someboyd know how to view the array numbers in HTMl with a click on the button?

Already thanks for helping me out!

**HTML:**

`JavaScript: 
  <span id="cijfer1"></span> <br>
  <button onclick="cijfer1()">Cijfer</button><br>`

**script:**

```
var cijfers = ["6.9", "7.2", "8.3", "8.2", "7.4", "7.8", "8.2", "7"];

function cijfer1(JavaScript){
document.getElementById("cijfer1").innerHTML = [1];
}
```

Comment: You should really try to spend some time improving the formatting of your questions.  Without it, it shows a lack of effort and people will avoid helping you.

Answer (score 1):

This will work.

---

**@ HTML**

```
<span id="cjifer"></span>
<button onclick={cijfer1}>
    Cijfer
</button>
```

**@ SCRIPT**

```
var cijfers = ["6.9", "7.2", "8.3", "8.2", "7.4", "7.8", "8.2", "7"];

function cijfer1(e){
  document.getElementById("cijfer1").innerHTML = cjifers[1];  // cjifers[1] == 2nd array element
}
```